# Problem with Windows Media Player ActiveX control in VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, activex, windows-media-player

it's me and my projects for school again. This time I wanted to insert a video into PowerPoint using file path via WMP ActiveX, so I drew one as follows: (`uiMode` set to `"none"`)

[image]

When the slide show starts, I transfer all data from an Excel file to the presentation, including the paths to the video. Then I hide the WMP with `Slide85.WMP.uiMode = "invisible"`.

When the time comes, I want the WMP to appear at the original size that i drawn and the linked video to play, so I used these codes:

```
Slide85.WMP_TT.uiMode = "none"
Slide85.WMP_TT.URL = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TT2.mp4"
Slide85.WMP_TT.Controls.Play
```

Already muted the video by changing the settings in the Properties tab.

Then the result came out like this:

[image]

The video still plays, but only with sound, which is impossible because I muted the control. No visual images is shown from the video, and the control's dimensions changes too.

As of now I cannot think of any causes to this problem. Please help me, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on this Microsoft help page, you have to set height and width parameters in code for the player to reserve the space when triggering uiMode="invisible": [Player.uiMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/player-uimode)

As an alternative, you can draw the size as you have done, then use VBA to hide or show it on the slide with code like this:

```
Sub HideWMP()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
                oShape.Visible = msoTrue
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried it, but there still remains the problem of the visual image from the video not showing while the sound still does. However when I go to the next slide and back, the video shows fully with both images and sound. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Turning off the visibility as in my second suggestion may solve the problem of non-displaying video.

Comment: Wait, that seems to make no sense... why am I turning off the visibility when I need the video to show up?

Comment: After drawing the video control, you would have to first hide it using oShape.Visible.msoFalse. Then at run-time you would show the video using the macro above.

Comment: Now there's another problem. I used this
```
Slide85.WMP_videoTT.settings.mute = True
```
to mute, and it mutes the whole application.